# Location of source command

Tags: ubuntu, bash

Where is the location of `source` command? When I enter `which source` I  get nothing.

```
$ which source
$
```

Any note?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`source` is an internal/built-in command in `bash`.

> A builtin is a command contained within the Bash tool set, literally built in. This is either for performance reasons -- builtins execute faster than external commands, which usually require forking off [1] a separate process -- or because a particular builtin needs direct access to the shell internals.

Source: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html

Comment: See also `help source` or `help .`, its portable synonym.